# Testing whether a function is virtual

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence), it is possible to perform a compile-time check using templates for whether a function with a given name and signature exists in a class.

Can we verify that a function exists with a given name and signature and that, in addition, it's `virtual`?

Comment: I don't think that can be done even at runtime in a portable way. In a non-portable way you could with knowledge of the ABI infer whether the function is virtual or not by storing a pointer to member and looking at the values, but you cannot do some of the required operations at runtime.

Comment: There's a horribly hackish implementation for unspecified versions of GCC & VC++ [here](http://trac.assembla.com/hippomocks/browser/trunk/HippoMocksTest/is_virtual.cpp?rev=64), if you're desperate enough.  Separately, you haven't said explicitly whether you also need the `is_virtual` test to be compile time...?